# Can console.log be styled with letter spacing?

Tags: javascript, css, console.log

I'm currently doing a mini-project in which you have to guess which word it is.
Currently, I'm using Chrome DevTools (text-game, not visual like a web page).

I decided to add some style into console.log.
Colors, size, and weight work well, but letter spacing doesn't.

Is it possible to add some letter spacing to the log?
Here's an example: console.log("This is just some test", "letter-spacing: 20px;")
Letters are not separated by spaces, it's normal.

Here is my example Script;

```
function word(){
    const answer = "WHITE"
    const input = prompt("Guess word")
    const userInput = input.toUpperCase()

    const letters = []
    let lStr = ``

    function style(color,size,weight){
        return `color:${color}; font-size: ${size}px; font-weight: ${weight}; letter-spacing: 2px;`
    }
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if( userInput[i] === answer[i] ){
            letters.push({str:`%c${userInput[i]}`, style:style("green","25","bold"), id:i})
        } else
        if( answer.includes(userInput[i]) ){
            letters.push({str:`%c${userInput[i]}`, style:style("yellow","25","bold"), id:i})
        } else {
            letters.push({str:`%c${userInput[i]}`, style:style("red","25","bold"), id:i})
        }
         
    }

    console.log(letters)
    for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        lStr += letters[j].str + " "
    }

    console.log(`${lStr}`, `${letters[0].style}`,`${letters[1].style}`,`${letters[2].style}`,`${letters[3].style}`,`${letters[4].style}`);


}
```

Note: Did add letters[j].str + " "
insteed of letters[j].str becuase letter-spacing din't work.

Comment: Not sure, but yeah, for some reason `letter-spacing` doesn't work in `console.log()`.

Answer (score 2):

The set of CSS styles that can be used in `console.log()` is browser-dependent. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#outputting_text_to_the_console) has the list for Firefox, but it's likely to be similar in other browsers.

> - `background` and its longhand equivalents
> - `border` and its longhand equivalents
> - `border-radius`
> - `box-decoration-break`
> - `box-shadow`
> - `clear` and `float`
> - `color`
> - `cursor`
> - `display`
> - `font` and its longhand equivalents
> - `line-height`
> - `margin`
> - `outline` and its longhand equivalents
> - `padding`
> - `text-*` properties such as `text-transform`
> - `white-space`
> - `word-spacing` and `word-break`
> - `writing-mode`

Unfortunately, `letter-spacing` is not among them.